# How set Proxy on AWS API Gateway using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have a lambda function that will handle PUT and GET requests using [Amazon API Gateway {proxy+}](http://www.1strategy.com/blog/2017/06/06/how-to-use-amazon-api-gateway-proxy/).
It is working correctly when all the settings are set manually by the Amazon Console. but I want to automate it using AWS Cloudformation.

To inform you, I will write steps to set `{proxy+}`:

1) create a simple [Lambda function](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/) and paste this lines of code inside it:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": 'text/html',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        "body": "Hello Reza Amya, Your Lambda is working..!"
    }
```

2) goto [Amazon API Gateway](https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/) and click on `Create API`.

3) choose `New API`, fill `API name`, select `Edge optimized` from the list for `Endpoint Type` then click on `Create API`

4) then your API is created and you should be on it's `Resources` page, if you are not, go to the `Resources` page for the created API.

5) from `Actions` select `Create Resource`

6) Select `Configure as proxy resource` (then it should change other fields automatically, if it doesn't, type `proxy` for `Resource Name` and `{proxy+}` for `Resource Path`) then click on `Create Resource`

7) Select `Lambda Function Proxy` for `Integration type` and select your lambda function from `Lambda Function` and click on `Save`

8) on the `Add Permission to Lambda Function` popup, click on `Ok`

9) from `Actions` click on `Deploy API`

10) Select `New Stage` from the list for `Deployment stage` then type a name for `Stage name` (for me, I have typed 'api') and click on `Deploy`

11) on the `stage` on the root page for your deployed API, you can see `Invoke URL`. click on it, and it will open new tab linked to somewhere like this: https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/

12) add a simple segment to end of your URL like this:
https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/**test**

now you should see bellow message in your browser page:

```
Hello Reza Amya, Your Lambda is working..!
```

Now the problem is I have written all these steps inside a Yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: My Lambda Function
Parameters:
  S3Bucket:
    Description: S3 Bucket where the Lambda code is
    Type: String
  S3Key:
    Description: S3 Key where the Lambda code is
    Type: String
  S3ObjectVersion:
    Description: Version of the S3 Key to use
    Type: String

Resources:
  apiGateway:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      Name: "my-api"
      Description: "My API"
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - EDGE

  Resource: 
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: 
        Ref: "apiGateway"
      ParentId: 
        Fn::GetAtt: 
          - "apiGateway"
          - "RootResourceId"
      PathPart: "{proxy+}"

  ProxyMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: ANY
      ResourceId: !Ref Resource
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.path.proxy: true
      Integration:
        CacheKeyParameters:
          - 'method.request.path.proxy'
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.path.proxy: 'method.request.path.proxy'
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
        Uri: !Sub
          - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Arn}/invocations
          - Arn:
              Fn::GetAtt:
               - LambdaFunction
               - Arn
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200 

  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment"
    DependsOn:
      - "ProxyMethod"
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      StageName: "dev"

  IAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'

      Policies:
        - PolicyName: Logging
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
        - PolicyName: AccessToDynamoDB
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'dynamodb:CreateTable'
                  - 'dynamodb:DeleteItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:DeleteTable'
                  - 'dynamodb:GetItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:GetRecords'
                  - 'dynamodb:UpdateItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:UpdateTable'
                  - 'dynamodb:PutItem'
                  - 'dynamodb:UpdateTable'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:*'

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: {Ref: S3Bucket}
        S3Key: {Ref: S3Key}
        S3ObjectVersion: {Ref: S3ObjectVersion}
      Handler: main.lambda_handler
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: {'Fn::GetAtt': [IAMRole, Arn]}
      Runtime: python3.6
      Timeout: 300

  LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt 
        - LambdaFunction
        - Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/*/*

Outputs:
  apiGatewayInvokeURL:
    Value: !Sub "https://${apiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${apiGateway}"

  lambdaArn:
    Value: !GetAtt "LambdaFunction.Arn"
```

The above Yaml file will create the Lambda function and will deploy the API, but it will show bellow error when I am trying to test the API:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

Can you please guide me what is wrong and how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related to you `IntegrationHttpMethod` setting. Although your APIGateway method is `ANY`, the `IntegrationHttpMethod` must always be `POST` for AWS Lambda.

This would lead to the following method declaration.

```
  ProxyMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: ANY
      ResourceId: !Ref Resource
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.path.proxy: true
      Integration:
        CacheKeyParameters:
          - 'method.request.path.proxy'
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.path.proxy: 'method.request.path.proxy'
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub
          - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Arn}/invocations
          - Arn:
              Fn::GetAtt:
               - LambdaFunction
               - Arn
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working now. it was around 2 days that I was working on it!